# iOS Device tracks nonexistent route

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

My app tracks user location with `CoreLocation` and `CoreMotion` frameworks. In some cases it tracks nonexistent routes. Device doesn't move, but sending location, speed and `automotive` activity type like it does. What can cause such behaviour?
[image]
[image]

LocationManager configuration

```
func update<T>(configuration: T) {
    if let configuration = configuration as? LocationManagerConfiguration {
        guard configuration.isActive else {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            return
        }
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = configuration.accuracy
        locationManager.distanceFilter = configuration.distanceFilter
    }
}
```

Handling locations

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var isAccepted = false

    for loc in locations where filtersManager.isAcceptable(location: loc) {
        print("All filters restrictions satisfied, accepting", logLevel: .DEBUG);
        var location = Api_Protobuf_Location()
        //setting protobuf model

        geoLocation.onNext(location)
        isAccepted = true
    }

    if !isAccepted {
        print("Some filters restrictions not satisfied, ignoring", logLevel: .DEBUG);
        geoLocation.onNext(nil)
    }
}
```

Handling activity

```
func start() {
    guard CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() else { return }

    activityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] result in
        guard let result = result else {
            self?.activity.onNext((nil, nil))
            return
        }

        let activity: Api_Protobuf_Activity
        switch self {
        case _ where result.automotive:
            activity = .inVehicle
        case _ where result.cycling:
            activity = .onBicycle
        case _ where result.running:
            activity = .running
        case _ where result.walking:
            activity = .walking
        case _ where result.stationary:
            activity = .still
        default:
            activity = .unknown
        }

        self?.activity.onNext((activity, result.confidence.rawValue))
    }

    pedometer.startUpdates(from: Date()) { [weak self] pedometerData, error in
        guard let pedometerData = pedometerData else {
            self?.steps.onNext(nil)
            return
        }

        if let error = error {
            self?.steps.onError(error)
            return
        }

        let steps = Steps(count: Int(truncating: pedometerData.numberOfSteps),
                          floorsUp: Int(truncating: pedometerData.floorsAscended ?? -1),
                          floorsDown: Int(truncating: pedometerData.floorsDescended ?? -1))
        self?.steps.onNext(steps)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured your `CLLocationAccuracy`, then it means the device is not getting accurate / consistent location service results. This is quite common, and usually happen when indoors, around tall obstructions and such. Nothing you can do about the data collected. All you can do is work with how you handle it, such as not updating the device location until it changes by a certain distance.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationaccuracy

Comment: Yes, I've set `CLLocationAccuracy`. Also I use `distanceFilter`, filtering locations by age and accuracy. Usually inaccurate locations appear in random directions. But in this case they are on one line and follow each other. Also `CoreMotion` framework which doesn't rely on GPS returns not `stationary` activity type